# Skip few number of row count(*) in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I am working on Archive type functionality, in this query number of post by month of a year showing. But my client requirement is that he don't want latest 50 post in this archive count. I tried my side but it's not working.

Table Design

```
Create Table tblBlogDetails
(
    UniqueKey UniqueIdentifier,
    BlogText NVARCHAR(MAX),
    BlogType Varchar(40),
    BlogingDateTime Datetime
)
```

Here is working code

```
 SELECT
        DATEPART(YEAR, BlogingDateTime) AS [BlogingYear],
        DATEPART(MONTH, BlogingDateTime) AS [BlogingMonth],
        CASE WHEN DATEPART(MONTH, BlogingDateTime) =1 THEN 'January'
             WHEN DATEPART(MONTH, BlogingDateTime) =2 THEN 'February'
             WHEN DATEPART(MONTH, BlogingDateTime) =3 THEN 'March'
             WHEN DATEPART(MONTH, BlogingDateTime) =4 THEN 'April'
             WHEN DATEPART(MONTH, BlogingDateTime) =5 THEN 'May'
             WHEN DATEPART(MONTH, BlogingDateTime) =6 THEN 'June'
             WHEN DATEPART(MONTH, BlogingDateTime) =7 THEN 'July'
             WHEN DATEPART(MONTH, BlogingDateTime) =8 THEN 'August'
             WHEN DATEPART(MONTH, BlogingDateTime) =9 THEN 'September'
             WHEN DATEPART(MONTH, BlogingDateTime) =10 THEN 'October'
             WHEN DATEPART(MONTH, BlogingDateTime) =11 THEN 'November'
             WHEN DATEPART(MONTH, BlogingDateTime) =12 THEN 'December' END AS BLogingMonthName,
        COUNT(*) AS NumberOfBlog 
    FROM tblBlogdetails
    WHERE UniqueKey=@UniqueKey AND
    BlogType='BLOG' 
    GROUP BY DATEPART(YEAR, BlogingDateTime) ,DATEPART(MONTH, BlogingDateTime) 
    ORDER BY DATEPART(YEAR, BlogingDateTime) DESC ,DATEPART(MONTH, BlogingDateTime);

/*
    Current OutPut
    BlogingYear BlogingMonth BLogingMonthName  NumberOfBlog
    2017        1            January           20
    2017        3            March             25
    2017        4            April             40

    Required OutPut
    2017        1            January           20
    2017        3            March             15
*/
```

Comment: Define "it's not working". And providing the table structure and some sample data would make this a lot better. Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: In the Required Output you probably mean to write 40 instead of 35...

Comment: Are you sure about required output? It does not correspond to `he don't want latest 50 post`.

Comment: @NikolaMarkovinović i have edit my required output. that was my mistake

Comment: `WHERE UniqueKey=@UniqueKey` seems wrong too.

Comment: @GiorgosAltanis i have to skip latest 50.. like in April user post 40 blog, in march 25 and jan 20 so according to latest 50. April and March 50 Blog will not show. In march it will show 15

Comment: You should move select from `tblBlogdetails` to cte, order by `BlogingDateTime` desc and use `offset 50` to skip newest rows. Then your main select can sum and group by remaining records.

Comment: @NikolaMarkovinović uniquekey is user uniquekey. so every user have there blog post.

Comment: You don't need that massive case expression to get the name of the month. You can replace that with this. "DATENAME(MONTH, BlogingDateTime) as BLogingMonthName"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added another filter. See if this works.

```
 SELECT
    DATEPART(YEAR, BlogingDateTime) AS [BlogingYear],
    DATEPART(MONTH, BlogingDateTime) AS [BlogingMonth],
    CASE WHEN DATEPART(MONTH, BlogingDateTime) =1 THEN 'January'
         WHEN DATEPART(MONTH, BlogingDateTime) =2 THEN 'February'
         WHEN DATEPART(MONTH, BlogingDateTime) =3 THEN 'March'
         WHEN DATEPART(MONTH, BlogingDateTime) =4 THEN 'April'
         WHEN DATEPART(MONTH, BlogingDateTime) =5 THEN 'May'
         WHEN DATEPART(MONTH, BlogingDateTime) =6 THEN 'June'
         WHEN DATEPART(MONTH, BlogingDateTime) =7 THEN 'July'
         WHEN DATEPART(MONTH, BlogingDateTime) =8 THEN 'August'
         WHEN DATEPART(MONTH, BlogingDateTime) =9 THEN 'September'
         WHEN DATEPART(MONTH, BlogingDateTime) =10 THEN 'October'
         WHEN DATEPART(MONTH, BlogingDateTime) =11 THEN 'November'
         WHEN DATEPART(MONTH, BlogingDateTime) =12 THEN 'December' END AS BLogingMonthName,
    COUNT(*) AS NumberOfBlog 
FROM tblBlogdetails
WHERE UniqueKey=@UniqueKey 
       AND
      BlogType='BLOG'
      AND
      UniqueKey NOT IN (SELECT TOP 50 UniqueKey
                        FROM tblBlogdetails
                        ORDER BY BlogingDateTime DESC)
GROUP BY DATEPART(YEAR, BlogingDateTime) ,DATEPART(MONTH, BlogingDateTime) 
ORDER BY DATEPART(YEAR, BlogingDateTime) DESC ,DATEPART(MONTH, BlogingDateTime);
```

Comment: Just fixed the code I added to Order By BlogingDateTime